# Что есть ANSI и ASCII

Tags: c, utf-8, ascii, ansi

Я бы хотел, наконец, разобраться, как правильно называть строки 8-ми битных символов.

Что такое строка символов **UTF-8** мне хорошо понятно - это строка, каждый символ которой представлен переменным количеством 8-ми битных блоков (байтов).

Что такое строки **UTF-16**/**UTF-32** мне тоже ясно.

Но я не могу понять, как корректно называть восьмибитные кодировки, где первые 128 знаков строго определены, а последующие - меняются в зависимости от используемой *кодовой страницы*.

Кто-то их называет **ascii**, кто-то **ansi**, или просто **CP1251**, если подразумевается конкретная кодировка.

Помогите разобраться. Гугл только запутал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ASCII** (American Standard Code for Information Interchange) - первый вариант кодировки.

Потом появились **CP866**, **KOI8-R**, **Windows 1251** и вот это всё.

Так что, **CP1251** - это расширенная версия **ASCII**.

**ANSI** - это расширения **ASCII**, в которых были удалены псевдографические элементы и добавлены символы типографики.

**CP1251** - это пример **ANSI** кодировки.

Если на диаграмме Эйлера показать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит все множество восьмибитных кодировок называет ANSI?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC не ASCII )

Answer (score 10):

**ASCII** (читается *аски́*) - это первая кодировка применявшаяся еще в пору когда 99% юзеров SO еще даже не родились (1963 год). Кодировка 7-битная, то есть определено 128 символов, 8-й бит полного байта использовался для проверки четности поскольку в то время каналы были ненадежные, то предполагалось что будет проверяться каждый полученный байт.

Далее со временем стало понятно, что для других языков можно использовать 8-й бит для отображения национальных символов - то есть использовать 256 символов. Эту расширенную 8-битовую кодировку условно называют **ANSI** (читается *анси́*) по названию американского института стандартов в рамках которого и была предложена 8-битовая кодировка. Соответственно, для каждого национального языка была предложена своя раскладка второй половины таблицы (от 128 до 255 символа), а первая половина таблицы от 0 до 127 - изначальные символы ASCII. KOI-8, CP-1251, 1252 и проч. - это различные инкарнации ANSI

Далее когда дело дошло до иероглифов стало понятно, что в 256 символов не уместиться и появилась **UNICODE** (читается *юникод*) - где на 1 символ отводится 2 байта, то есть 65536 символов, где таблица была жестко поделена между национальными символами, например таблица ASCII осталась в интервале `U+0000 до U+007F`, а наша с вами кириллица в интервале `U+A640 до U+A69F` ну и т.д.

С нарастанием угара стало ясно что 65536 символов также не хватает, потому что появились эмодзи, стали поднимать голову другие национальные символы справедливо указывавшие на нехватку места в таблице UNICODE, тогда был предложен **UTF-8** (читается *ютиэф 8*), где количество байтов в символе имеет разную длину и может быть от 1-го до 4 байт, что дает 1 112 064 символов.

Вот, как то так.

Comment: UTF-8 это же просто формат представления точки в юникоде, как и UTF-16/UTF-32. Сам юникод не двух байтовый, и даже не трех.

Comment: Это сейчас так. В начальной версии юникод было 2 байта, потом он стал дополняться

Comment: Поучительная [статья](http://losingfight.com/blog/2006/07/28/wchar_t-unsafe-at-any-size/) затрагивающая формат мутаций utf8 :)

Answer (score 5):

Считаю название «восьмибитные» или «однобайтовые кодировки» вполне корректным *общим* названием для подобных вещей.

Само собой, если подразумевается какая-то *конкретная* кодовая страница/кодировка, то она и указывается: «KOI8-R», «CP1251» «CP1250», «ISO8859-5».

ASCII как стандарт (а это действительно стандарт — American standard code for information interchange) определяет, если я правильно помню, только первые 127 кодов символов. Поэтому формально символы типа «я», «č», «њ», «Ḱ» не принадлежат ASCII.

«ANSI» — это вообще исключительно русскоязычный (*sic!*) термин для CP1251, т.к. вообще-то это сокращение обозначает американский национальный институт стандартизации (а «OEM» — original equipment manufacturer).